# A simple children's riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> Here is a riddle written on a cup:
>
> **Eh** is four times as much as **Oi**,
>
> **Oh** is four times as little as **Ai**,
>
> What do you get if you add all four of them up?

Source: Russian Olympiad Problems, Math Circle (Beginner) [2018 PDF](https://circles.math.ucla.edu/circles/lib/data/Handout-1539-1497.pdf) Q6

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, seems a nice question!

Comment: Old Macdonald ?

Comment: Appears to be from the [2018 russian olympiad](https://circles.math.ucla.edu/circles/lib/data/Handout-1539-1497.pdf) (Q6)

Comment: This surely seems too broad, unless the cup part is important somehow... but I'm of the opinion it's just for rhyming purposes

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh I didn't know that! I was told it by a friend.  Good find.

Comment: It's solvable. Solution on the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing equations from the poem:

> $EH = 4 \times OI$
>  $AI = 4 \times OH$

So we know that O is

> 1 or 2

And then we have

> $H \times 4 = xI$
>  $I \times 4 = xH$

So H and I are

> (2,8), (4,6), (6,4), or (8,2)

So OH is

> 12, 14, 16, 18, 24, 26, or 28

and AI is

> 48, 56, ~64~, 72, 96, ~104~, or ~112~ (~crossing out~ the ones that duplicate digits or are three digits)

So (OH,AI,OI) are

> (12,48,18), (14,56,16), (18,72,12), or (24,96,26)

Then (OH,AI,OI,EH) are

> (12,48,18,72), ~(14,56,16,64)~, (18,72,12,48), or ~(24,96,26,104)~ again ~crossing out~ the ones that duplicate digits or are three digits

Which leaves

> (12,48,18,72) or (18,72,12,48)

So the sum is

> 150 no matter which of these you choose

Comment: I don't understand the first line of your solution. Why can't O be 0?

Comment: We don't typically write numbers starting with 0, but I guess you could create a solution where O is 0 if you wanted to.

Answer (score 4):

> I and H are both even, and, from the rhyme, I+H=10 is easy to deduce. Also O=1 or O=2. But if O=2, then one of OH, OI is greater than $25$. so O=1. The riddle asks for EH+OI+OH+AI=5(OI+OH)=150.

Comment: How are you using the rhyme exactly?

Comment: @Anush; $4i\equiv h \pmod{10}$ and $4h\equiv i \pmod{10}$ gives you $h,i\equiv 0 \pmod2$. Adding gives $3(i+h)\equiv 0 \pmod{10} \implies i+h\equiv 0 \pmod{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have Eh = 4Oi, Ai = 4Oh, which constrains the smaller values to the range 10..25.

So i = 16h, mod 10, which has 2 solutions 0 (reject so that i $\neq$ h), and i = 6.

With the above constraint on Oi, O=1, so Oi = 16, Eh = 64, Oh = 14, and Ai = 56.

The sum of the 4 2-digit numbers is then 150.